# Recyclerview scroll lag

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have multiple elements in my recyclerview's row -> By multiple I mean multiple in number as well as multiple in type i.e mutliple imageviews, textviews etc.
Following is the gist so that you can see all the elements: https://gist.github.com/Harshhb101/55e25da72e3a474aeeb422d5e231d3e3

The issue is that I need to hide/show these elements based on a parameter which can have upto 10 values. Thus I will have 10 types of rows. Currently I have created only one layout for the row have elements for all types of rows and in some mobiles, the scroll has a lag. Majorly I am getting the lag where the rows have images. I am using Glide to load the images. Following is the gist for the onBindView: https://gist.github.com/Harshhb101/e10feb2cccda9d698ff06487bbb879ef

I did look up on stackoverflow but could not find anything solid but came upon using multiple viewholders. My question is that if I refactor my code, will it make a substantial difference by using multiple viewholders? Or is there something wrong in my approach that could be fixed to get a good scoll.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your RecyclerView images smaller to save memory and cache them. Read [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/best-strategy-to-load-images-using-glide-image-loading-library-for-android-e2b6ba9f75b2).

Also if your ViewHolder contains images that has size wrap_content then images are loaded full size what is really bad for performance for example if view size on screen is 48dp x 48dp and picture is full HD, then full HD drawable going to be loaded in to memory what is making your scrolling slow and not smooth.

I suggest using fixed size in ViewHolder or override image size when loading in Glide

Comment: The reason I have the width as wrap content is to maintain the aspect ratio of the image as the images can we of multiple aspect ratios. If I fix the size, I won't be able to maintain the Aspect Ratio :(

Comment: I suggest using attrs.xml for different screen sizes. And also you can try to use https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-thumbnails to reduce size

Comment: I am sorry.. but the reason I am not fixing the size is not because of the different screen sizes on the different devices but because I will be getting images of different sizes and aspect ratios from the server.

Comment: so use cropCenter and fixed size of ImageView then it will crop aspect ratio automatically

Comment: if it going to work please mark question as answered

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the code i found couple of improvements.

1. Don't make God ViewType (One view type for all kind of views). instead create 
   individual viewtype for each kind of posts. so it'll eliminate the rendering cost of all the views and making them visible and invisble at runtime.
   [Reference demo of recyclerview with multiple viewtypes](https://medium.com/@ruut_j/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-item-types-bce7fbd1d30e)
2. Use some image loading libraries so that you dont have to handle caching images and bitmap related manipulations (Picasso will be good).
   [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)
3. And lastly avoid doing heavy tasks in `onbind()` instead prepare your data class specifically for recyclerview (if much caluclation required like heavy string manipulations etc) before setting recyclerview adapter.

Comment: I am already using Glide as the image loading library.
My concern is that if I refactor my code, will it make a substantial difference by using multiple viewtypes?

Comment: Yes, because you don't have inflate all the views and then making them visible and invisible manually. if you create seperate viewType you'll only inflate what views actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

- Please declare many view type instead of one view type for many kind. It's actually make the code more readability, but not much the reduce the lag because the recycle view/listview is have the reused mechanism.
- Recommended to use fixed size in RecycleView.
- I saw the Glide used for image loading. So did you config the cache?
- I have doubt that you loading the big resolution image

Comment: When you say fixed size, do you mean for the images? The reason of not doing so is to maintain the aspect ratio of the images as the images can be of variable sizes and aspect ratios

Comment: I did not config the cache, will look up how to do it